# Check repeated records mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with records of two variables `(a, b)` and an `id`, just like this:

```
a,b,id    
x,y,1    
x,y,2    
x,z,3    
t,z,4    
t,y,5
t,y,6
t,y,7
```

For every id, I want to check, using mysql, wether every pair of (a, b) variables has appeared before, and assign this to a variable. For instance, the output of the previous input should be:

```
a,b,id,repeated    
x,y,1,1 - this should be 1 not zero    
x,y,2,1    
x,z,3,0   
t,z,4,0    
t,y,5,0
t,y,6,1
t,y,7,1
```

I should do that for a relatively big table (700000 rows), and therefore I'd rather not use slow methods. Any thoughts?

We also cannot assume that only previous ID's have repeated data, hence query must take into account id's not being equal to each other.

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: My version is 5.7.19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a correlated subquery here:

```
SELECT
    a,
    b,
    id,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                      WHERE t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b AND t2.id < t1.id)
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS repeated
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: To the editor: If we don't assume some order, then the `repeated` column will always have `1` everywhere.  There needs to be some "first" value which would be assigned to `0`.

Comment: I realized later that OP asked for repeated values to be assigned 1 only. +1 for direct approach instead of session variables.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using [User-defined Session variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j4zpTwokCNx3xMLQQMEGFE/0)

```
SELECT 
  IF(@a_var = dt.a AND 
     @b_var = dt.b, 
     1, 
     0) AS repeated, 
  @a_var := dt.a AS a, 
  @b_var := dt.b AS b, 
  dt.id 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    a, 
    b, 
    id
  FROM your_table 
  ORDER BY a,b,id
) AS dt 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a_var := '', 
                   @b_var := '') AS user_init_vars
```

Comment: I have always been somewhat terrified of MySQL session variables.  Hopefully with the advent of MySQL 8+ which support analytic functions, there won't be as much need for them.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just suggesting one of the possible ways out there. With window functions in MySQL 8+, definitely life is much simpler now

Comment: Not saying your answer is bad +1, just saying that analytic functions make it much easier to do such queries.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
select @aLag := '1', @bLag := '1';
select id, a, b, isRepeated from (
  select case when @aLag = a and @bLag = b then 1 else 0 end isRepeated,
         @ALag := a a,
         @bLag := b b,
         id
  from tbl
  order by a, b, id
) a order by id
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wj35Z7Ni23iMYGd4kmVffF/0)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an uncorrelated method...

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'x' AS a, 'y' AS b, 1 AS id UNION ALL
    SELECT 'x', 'y', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'x', 'z', 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 't', 'z', 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 't', 'y', 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 't', 'y', 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 't', 'y', 7
)

SELECT DISTINCT x.*
              , y.a IS NOT NULL repeated
  FROM yourTable x
  LEFT
  JOIN yourTable y 
    ON y.a = x.a 
   AND y.b = x.b
   AND y.id < x.id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=924d776f772007af9d46f36a5daaf8e2